# Responsive tables with jQuery mobile and ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

Here is a way to create jQuery Mobile's responsive tables with an ASP.NET gridview.

**ASP.NET** (Reflow Example)

```
Protected Sub gv_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles gv.DataBound
    gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    gv.Attributes.Add("data-role", "table")
    gv.Attributes.Add("data-mode", "reflow")

    Dim headerCells = gv.HeaderRow.Cells
    headerCells(3).Attributes.Add("data-priority", "2")
    headerCells(4).Attributes.Add("data-priority", "2")
End Sub
```

**QUESTION**

When my gridview returns no results I receive error : *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

I presume this is because the gridview has nothing to bind to however the gridview still renders as a table.

Can anyone conceive why this may be occuring and how it can be fixed?

**THE FIX**

To fix this be sure to add ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" to your gridview to ensure the thead tag is still rendered when empty.

Comment: It might be because there is no HeaderRow created since there is no data.  Try checking to see if there is a HeaderRow before accessing its Cells

Comment: I agree this is probably the cause of the problem.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to work at two levels here:

(1) Use `EmptyDataTemplate` or `EmptyDataText` to ensure the empty GridView renders with an html markup which is totally in your control. However, you may still need to avoid the `databind`. See below.

Identify how you are databinding the GridView:

If you are doing it manually thru code with data coming from your data access layer then you can conditionally bind it. e.g. if your data source is a `list`, then first check if that list contains data or not:

```
If myList.Any then
    MyGrid.DataSource = myList 
    MyGrid.DataBind()
Else
    'take evasive measures here
End If
```

This way you will avoid a call to your GridView's `DataBind` handler and save you from "object reference" errors.

(2) Alternatively, you may want to look at the `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` property set to `true` on the GridView. This way, a table will still get created and your `databind` code will not produce "object reference" errors. You need an `EmptyDataTemplate` for `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` to work.

Comment: Option (2) for the win. I love the easy fixes. I wasn;t even aware of the ShowHeaderWhenEmpty property. Many thanks @abhitalks =)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for Empty GridView IF for Empty GridView no need to execute your code in DataBound Event like this.

```
Protected Sub gv_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles gv.DataBound
    If gv.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        gv.Attributes.Add("data-role", "table")
        gv.Attributes.Add("data-mode", "reflow")

        Dim headerCells = gv.HeaderRow.Cells
        headerCells(3).Attributes.Add("data-priority", "2")
        headerCells(4).Attributes.Add("data-priority", "2")
    End If
End Sub
```